# Automatically receive the current billing cycle's data usage update from cellular providers at pre-determined frequency?

Tags: ios, att

With AT&T, I can text `*DATA#` from my iPhone to get data usage for the current billing cycle.

Is there any way to do this programmatically, say I automatically receive text every Wednesday at 13:00?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I'm glad you've asked here, since this question isn't on-topic on Stack Overflow. Cross-posting is also discouraged in all cases since it splits the answers. I've voted to close your question on Stack Overflow and you are welcome to remove it over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Shortcuts app to automate actions on iPhone. It's not possible to completely automate the action of sending a text message, but you can have Shortcuts prompt you at a specific date/time and send the message with one tap.

1. From the Shortcuts app, create a new Personal Automation at your desired Time of Day.
2. Add a Message action to send a message with your text to a number of your choice.
   Disable ‘Show When Run’ to run the shortcut immediately on trigger without opening the app.

   [image]
   [image]
3. When the time occurs, tap the notification to run the shortcut:

   [image]